# How to migrate SonarQube to new host

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

Need to migrate my SonarQube to a new server (not the remote DB, just the application). Is there any special tool offered by Sonar to do so? is it just a matter of pointing this new installation (if possible) to the old DB?

Sonar v5.2
MySQL 5.x

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this regularly as the servers I run on are only provisioned for 30 days. You don't specify the operating system, but for windows it's as simple as:

1. Stop "old" service
2. Copy folder from old machine to new machine
3. Install the windows service with the java wrapper
4. Start the service
5. In my case I change the DNS alias after the service is running

Comment: Just as a note, @Mike's procedure copies the old ElasticSearch index and the logs. At a minimum, it would probably be cleaner to remove the contents of $SONARQUBE_HOME/data and let the ES index be rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks Mike! mine is CentOS7, but the generals would apply as well, I assume. I don't use ES, and I want to keep any data existing now, after the migration, so I'd go and migrate /sonar home dir as is. Thanks both!